# Webpage goes long after isotope initializes

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, jquery-isotope

I'm using isotope + bootstrap and I have isotope initialize after all images have been loaded. The issue is after it loads, there's all this blank space at the bottom where the page used to run to. Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Relevant URL: http://www.viridian-graphics.com/

JS initialize code:

```
$(function() {
// FIRE EVENTS ON SPECIFIC MEDIA QUERY BREAKS
mql('all and (max-width: 320px)', reLayout);    
mql('all and (max-width: 480px)', reLayout);
mql('all and (max-width: 768px)', reLayout);
mql('all and (min-width: 980px)', reLayout);
mql('all and (min-width: 1200px)', reLayout);

$posts = $('#posts');

clear();

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $posts.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        animationEngineString: 'best-available',
        filter : '.initial-load',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        resizable: true,
        resizesContainer: true,
        //transformsEnabled: false,
        getSortData: {
            category : function ($elem) {
                return $elem.attr('data-category');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I just reverted to my old code and it's working properly again.